# Samba ADS: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller, kerberos, samba4

I followed this [Setting up Samba as an Active Directory Domain Controller - wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller) and all seems fine (`kinit`,`klist`,`net ads user`,`net ads group` work).

Adding users without password also works, but if I set any password, it fails:

`net ads user add tester test1234`

Error:

> Could not add user tester. Error setting password Cannot contact any
>   KDC for requested realm

I have read and tried the answers of several similar questions like:

[Kerberos Login Failed: Cannot resolve network address for KDC in requested realm - Kerio and Open Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/391044/kerberos-login-failed-cannot-resolve-network-address-for-kdc-in-requested-realm)

[Samba4 & Active Directory Kerberos [Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'INTERNAL.CORP.COM' while getting initial credentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/724574/samba4-active-directory-kerberos-cannot-contact-any-kdc-for-realm-internal-c)

[winbindd: kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm](https://serverfault.com/questions/586412/winbindd-kinit-succeeded-but-ads-sasl-spnego-krb5-bind-failed-cannot-contact-a)

... and more

I also reinstalled the OS several times. Over a clean installation,  the only additional packages installed are: `samba`, `krb5-user`, `libpam-krb5`, `winbind`, `libpam-winbind`, `ldb-tools`, `ntp`, `smbclient`, `smbldap-tools`

Versions:

- Ubuntu Server 18.04 x64 (kernel 4.15.0-30-generic)
- samba 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.2

My config files:

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    dns forwarder = 192.168.10.30
    netbios name = ADS3
    realm = AAA-AAA.NET
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = AAA-AAA
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/aaa-aaa.net/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
```

**/etc/krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = AAA-AAA.NET
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
    AAA-AAA.NET = {
        kdc = ads3.aaa-aaa.net:88
        admin_server = ads3.aaa-aaa.net
    }

[domain_realm]
    .aaa-aaa.net = AAA-AAA.NET
    aaa-aaa.net = AAA-AAA.NET
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
192.168.10.33 ads3.aaa-aaa.net ads3
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
domain aaa-aaa.net
search aaa-aaa.net
nameserver 192.168.10.30
```

Note: `systemd-resolved` was disabled to prevent resolv.conf to be updated.

Output:

**nmap localhost**

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53/tcp    open  domain
88/tcp    open  kerberos-sec
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
389/tcp   open  ldap
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
464/tcp   open  kpasswd5
636/tcp   open  ldapssl
3268/tcp  open  globalcatLDAP
3269/tcp  open  globalcatLDAPssl
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
```

**net ads info**

```
LDAP server: 192.168.10.33
LDAP server name: ads3.aaa-aaa.net
Realm: AAA-AAA.NET
Bind Path: dc=AAA-AAA,dc=NET
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Wed, 15 Aug 2018 14:35:33 JST
KDC server: 192.168.10.33
Server time offset: 0
```

**dig -t srv _kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> -t srv _kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 34079
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net.    IN  SRV

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.10.30#53(192.168.10.30)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 15 14:37:09 JST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

Note: the DNS server (at 192.168.10.30) is running dnsmasqd and is working properly. `ads3.aaa-aaa.net` resolves to `192.168.10.33`.

**kadmin**

```
Authenticating as principal administrator/admin@AAA-AAA.NET with password.
kadmin: Client 'administrator/admin@AAA-AAA.NET' not found in Kerberos database while initializing kadmin interface
```

I have also look into the `kadmin` error without success. I tried installing `krb5-kdc` and `krb5-admin-server`, but they interfere with the setup (unable to use `kinit`).

Any help appreciated.

### Update 1

According to `Michael` in the only answer (until now) for the question [Samba4 and Kerberos configuration on a dedicated server](https://serverfault.com/a/699331/72881), there is no need to install krb5-kdc/krb5-admin-server separately, so that is not it.

We found that the DNS response in our setup was mistaken, `samba_dnsupdate --verbose --all-names` was reporting:

> dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: The DNS query name does not exist

so we added the next rules into `dnsmasq.conf` at our DNS server (192.168.10.30):

```
server=/aaa-aaa.net/192.168.10.33
srv-host=_ldap._tcp.aaa-aaa.net,ads3.aaa-aaa.net,389
srv-host=_kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net,ads3.aaa-aaa.net,88
```

We tested them from another computer, with:

```
host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.aaa-aaa.net.
host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net.
```

And now the response is now fine. Example:

> _kerberos._udp.aaa-aaa.net has SRV record 0 0 88 ads3.aaa-aaa.net.

Also `samba_dnsupdate --verbose --all-names` output seems correct.

**Current status at this point:**

`kadmin` (same as before)

> kadmin: Client 'administrator/admin@AAA-AAA.NET' not found in Kerberos
>   database while initializing kadmin interface

`net ads user add tester test1234`

> Could not add user tester. Error setting password Operation not permitted

### Update 2

We were able to set user passwords with other commands:

`pdbedit -a -u tester` (password input will prompt)
`samba-tool user setpassword --newpassword=test1234 tester`

We were able to connect from Windows, so its solved for the moment. If anyone knows why `kadmin` fails and why `net` command is unable to set passwords, I will accept that answer.